# How to use iomanip to make multiple out strings occupy a certain width together?

Tags: c++

I know setw(n) only works for the string that directly follows it. Like:

```
cout<<setw(10)<<"A"<<" String"<<endl;
```

Gives out this:

```
          A String
```

with 9 spaces before A.

But I want some sort of command like this:

```
cout<<[something here to set the space for all coming things]<<"A"<<" String"<<endl;
```

To provide this:

```
    A String
```

With "A" and " String" uses 10 chars together, only 2 spaces before A.

Is there a way to do that? Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: To user1034749 ： I tried cout.width(10) but the result is all the same with setw thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. The `setw()` manipulator only applies to the next output.

What you must do, then, is combine the things you wish to have a certain width into a string, then output that string. For example:

```
{
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << "X = " << X << ".";
  cout << setw(15) << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

If you also want to crop the output to fit the width (and not overflow), you can adjust the output to produce a maximum width:

```
  cout << setw(15) << ss.str().substr(0,15) << "\n";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious possibility would be to create a single string containing the two fields, then set the width for the combined whole. Given string literals, the obvious way would be to convert each to a string, then concatenate the strings.

Assuming a recent compiler, you can do that pretty easily like this:

```
cout << setw(10) << ("A"s + "string") << "\n";
```

If the values involved aren't really string literals, you can convert the inputs to strings first:

```
int a = 1, b = 100;

cout << setw(10) << (to_string(a) + to_string(b));
```